# C# type generic parameter determination

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a problem with automatic type determination. I am trying to create generic method for generic **Rtf** style creation (`RtfElement.StyleOfType<,>`). But this keyword is not assumed as `TElement : RtfElement` type by compiler. I have no idea why its happens, because `TElement` has `RtfElement` type restriction.

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract Rtf style.
/// </summary>
public abstract class RtfStyle<TElement>
    where TElement : RtfElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates Rtf style of the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TStyle">Rtf style type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="styleOwner">Style owner</param>
    /// <returns>Rtf style</returns>
    public static TStyle Create<TStyle>(TElement styleOwner)
        where TStyle : RtfStyle<TElement>, new()
    {
        if (styleOwner == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("styleOwner");
        }

        return new TStyle
        {
            StyleOwner = styleOwner
        };
    }

    #region Protected Fields

    protected TElement StyleOwner;

    #endregion
}
```

Following code cannot be compiled at this line:

```
style = RtfStyle<TElement>.Create<TStyle>(this);
```

Compiler error: `"this is not assignable to parameter type TElement":`

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract Rtf element.
/// </summary>
public abstract class RtfElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets Rtf style of the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TElement">Rtf element type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TStyle">Rtf style type</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Rtf style</returns>
    protected TStyle StyleOfType<TElement, TStyle>()
        where TElement : RtfElement
        where TStyle : RtfStyle<TElement>, new()
    {
        var style = Style.OfType<TStyle>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (style != null)
        {
            return style;
        }

        style = RtfStyle<TElement>.Create<TStyle>(this);

        Style.Add(style);

        return style;
    }

    #region Protected Fields

    protected readonly List<IRtfWritable> Style = new List<IRtfWritable>();

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following line of code

```
style = RtfStyle<TElement>.Create<TStyle>(this);
```

What happens is you call a static method in `RtfStyle<TElement>` called `Create` with the type `TStyle`. This means the parameter for the method must be `TElement`, and you are sending `this`.

Since `this` is `RtfElement` which does not inherit `TElement` - your code fails to compile.

Comment: I think the following line `where TElement : RtfElement` should define the TElement is RtfElement type or some of it's inherited types.

Comment: `RtfElement` cannot be safely cast to `TElement`. `TElement` can be safely cast to `RtfElement`.